# How to only extract first value from list of JSON Array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have data array which is like `{date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68}`

I  only want to extract all dates so the result is like:

```
{date: "2019-10-08"}
{date: "2019-11-08"}
{date: "2019-12-08"}
```

I have tried the line of code below but it only gives me all the date values like

`resultArr.forEach(AllDate => dateArr.push(AllDate.date));`

`["2019-10-08","2019-11-08","2019-12-08"]` this is not what i want.

i would like the text "date" i am looking for this.

```
{date: "2019-10-08"}
{date: "2019-11-08"}
{date: "2019-12-08"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just push an object like this:

```
resultArr.forEach(AllDate => {
 dateArr.push({date: AllDate.date});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let array1 = [{ date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68 },
{ date: "2019-11-08", value0: 68 },
{ date: "2019-12-08", value0: 68 }];;

let res = array1.map(({date}, index) => {
    return { date }
})
console.log(res);
```

Using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let resultArr = [{ date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68 },
{ date: "2019-11-08", value0: 68 },
{ date: "2019-12-08", value0: 68 }];;

let dateArr = [];
resultArr.forEach(AllDate => dateArr.push({date: AllDate.date}));
console.log(dateArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

plz try this

```
let result = [{date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68}, 
{date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68}, 
{date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68}, 
{date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68}];

let dateArr = [];

result.forEach(AllDate => dateArr.push({date : AllDate.date}));

console.log(dateArr);
```

With map()

```
let dateArr = result.map((value, key) => return {date : value.date} );
console.log(dateArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [**Destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
var data = [{date: "2019-10-08", value0: 68},
{date: "2019-11-08", value0: 69},
{date: "2019-12-08", value0: 70}];

var resultArr = data.map(({date}) => ({date}));
console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let dateArray = resultArr.map(AllDate => return {date:AllDate.date} );
```